# Why does React not delete the required component but deletes the last sibling?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, state

```
import * as React from "react";

const Node = ({ setSelfStateOnParent, removeSelfFromParent, id }) => {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    name: "",  // Stores name of node
    children: [],  // Stores the children of this node (sub-nodes)
  });

  function updateName(updatedName) {
    setState({ ...state, name: updatedName });
  }

  function updateChildren(updatedChildren) {
    setState({ ...state, children: updatedChildren });
  }

  function addChild() {
    updateChildren([...state.children, { name: "", children: [] }]);
  }

  React.useEffect(() => {
    /* If this is a sub-node, update element in parent's
     * state.children array containing info about this sub-node
     */
    if (setSelfStateOnParent) {
      setSelfStateOnParent(state);
    }
  }, [state]);

  return (
    <div className="Node">
      <header>
        <div className="name">
          <span>{id}</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
          {/* Text field to update state.name */}
          <input
            type="text"
            value={state.name}
            onChange={(e) => updateName(e.target.value)}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="btn_group">
          <button
            onClick={() => {
              addChild();
            }}
          >
            add child
          </button>
          {removeSelfFromParent && (
            <button
              onClick={() => {
                if (removeSelfFromParent) removeSelfFromParent();
              }}
            >
              delete
            </button>
          )}
        </div>
      </header>
      {state.children && (
        <ul className="children">
          {state.children.map((child, childIndex) => (
            <li className="child_node" key={childIndex}>
              <Node
                id={childIndex}
                setSelfStateOnParent={(childState) => {
                  // Copy parent's children array to edit and update
                  const updatedChildren = [...state.children];
                  /*
                   * Updates the array with sub-nodes own state
                   */
                  updatedChildren[childIndex] = { ...childState };
                  updateChildren(updatedChildren);
                }}
                removeSelfFromParent={() => {
                  const updatedChildren = [...state.children];
                  /* Removes this sub-node's info from
                   * parent's state.children
                   */
                  const removedChild = updatedChildren.splice(childIndex, 1);
                  updateChildren(updatedChildren);
                }}
              />
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Node;
```

When I try to debug in React DevTools, the element of `state.children` that I want to delete is deleted, but it still shows up in the front end.
e.g. When there are child nodes with indices 0..4, I press **delete** on the component with index `2`; In React DevTools, the component with index `2` gets deleted, but it deletes component with index `4` in the front-end

Comment: A couple of tips that _may_ be related - split your state out into 2 different state properties, `name` and `children`.  If you ever use the existing state when setting new state, use the callback method, e.g, setState((prevState) => ({...prevState, ...newState})).  Don't use the index from a map as your `key` for a list item, use a static property, e.g. `child.id`

Comment: Thank you. I tried both solutions but it is still having the same result. As asked in the question, the component state DOES update in the desired manner, but the front end DOM does not